# Writing DAX to return specific dates and total quantity of those dates within a date interval

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have two tables with many-to-many relationship and I want to **write a DAX** that returns every invoice and total quantity of those invoices within a date interval. Please help!! Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: Please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Show your sample data with your expected output.